# Finding proper descendants of an integer

Tags: c, algorithm, binary

I'm stuck on an basic algorithmic issue and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Basically I wanna list all numbers that are proper descendants of an integer. That is to say, if my number is 21, I want to use its binary representation (10101) and list all numbers which have at least one common bit of value 1 with 21 and are lower than 21. The result here should be 10100, 10001, 10000, 101, 100, 1.

The mathematical definition of proper descendants is as follows:

- Let h be a nonnegative number less than 2^m. `h = d0 + d1*2^1 + ... + dm-1*2^(m-1)` where di = 0 or 1.
- Let h' be another nonnegative such as `h' = d0' + d1'*2^1 + ... + dm-1'*2^(m-1)` where di' = 0 or 1.
- h' is a descendant of h if di'<=di for 0<=i<m

I've tried many implementations in both Python and C and tried the old pen and paper technique, but all of them failed. I know it's rather simple but I can't seem to figure it out.  I'm coding in C so if you find a solution that works in C that would be ideal, but I'd take anything right now.

Comment: We're happy you're here with us and we need to see your code to help you debug it. If you don't have an algo, please develop that first.

Comment: Failed with pen-and-paper? How so?

Comment: Here is one idea: Go over all the `1` bits, turn them to zero one by one. Then for each of the results run the algorithm recursively to find the "descendants" of "descendants".

Comment: Consider all integers with `k` bits, where `k` is the number of 1 in your initial number. There are 2^k-1 such numbers. By excluding the all-zero case, you get 2^k-2 solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry I dont have any code to show you. It's a small algorithm that I wanna use as a bigger part in a research project and that's really just how I presented it. I tried recursive methods but I'll give it another shot

Comment: "list all numbers which have at least one common bit of value 1" Then the correct answer would also include 11, 111 and so on. Something in your specification is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't exactly know how to explain it without being too much into maths, hence the example. I'll add the mathematical definition.

Comment: Hint: the number in the set of descendants is a power of 2 including the original.

Comment: `&` in Python and C is your friend

Comment: In Python: `for n in range(21+1): if n&21: print(bin(n))`

Comment: Take the original apart into powers of 2 (21=16+4+1), make a [powerset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) of those, for each of the sets in the powerset make a sum, the list of sums is the list of descendants you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple approach: enumerate all integers between `n-1` and `1` and print those that are strictly included in `n`, ie: `(i & n) == i`.

```
void list_descendants(int n) {
    printf("descendants of %d:", n);
    for (int i = n; i --> 1;) {
        if ((i & n) == i)
            printf(" %d", i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: the first print is missing an argument but I think this is the best solution here. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally came up with a code in C that is far from good looking and probably horribly optimised but still works as intended. There are probably much simpler solutions but here is mine for knowledge purposes :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned int pui(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
  if (b == 0)
    return 1;
  if (b == 1)
    return a;
  if (b % 2 == 0)
    return pui(a * a, b / 2);
  else
    return pui(a * a, (b - 1) / 2);
}
unsigned int testBit(unsigned int h, unsigned int offset)
{
  unsigned int mask = 1 << offset;
  return (h & mask);
}

bool isInList(unsigned int x, unsigned int *output_size, unsigned int **output)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < *output_size; i++)
  {
    if (*(*output + i) == x)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
void listDescendants(unsigned int h, unsigned int *output_size, unsigned int **output, int *currently_processing)
{
  unsigned int max_offset = 0;
  unsigned int temp_h = h;
  unsigned int initial_output_size = *output_size;
  while (temp_h > 0)
  {
    max_offset++;
    temp_h /= 2;
  }
  unsigned int h_radix2[max_offset];
  for (int i = 0; i < max_offset; i++)
  {
    if (testBit(h, i))
    {

      if (h > pui(2, i) && !isInList(h - pui(2, i), output_size, output))
      {
        *(*output + *output_size) = h - pui(2, i);
        *output_size += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  if (*currently_processing < (int)*output_size)
  {
    *currently_processing += 1;
    listDescendants(*(*output + *currently_processing), output_size, output, currently_processing);
  }
}


int main()
{
  
  int currently_processing = -1;
  unsigned int size = 0;
  unsigned int *output = malloc(300 * sizeof(unsigned int));
  listDescendants(21, &size, &output, &currently_processing);

  printf("size = %u\n", size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    printf("%u ", output[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering what `pui` is. And where are the `#include`s?

Comment: pui is just a basic exponentiation function (pui(2,i) return 2^i). I forgot to include the file. Includes are the following (adding them to the file): #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Comment: `pui` is overkill. You can write 2^n as `1<<n`. That's probably 100 times faster. Read about the `<<` operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive solution, such as the following one.

I'm a bit lazy, so I didn't put the numbers in a list but simply printed them, and I also printed 0 and the given number.

I believe you can easily adjust the code so it will do what you desire.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHAR_BIT 8

void ProperDescendantsRecursive(unsigned int num, unsigned int bit_index)
{
    if (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned int) - 1 == bit_index)
    {
        printf("%u\n", num);
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int mask = 1U << bit_index;
        if (num & mask)
        {
            /* with the bit at index bit_index is off */
            ProperDescendantsRecursive(num ^ mask, bit_index + 1);
            /* with the bit at index bit_index is on */
            ProperDescendantsRecursive(num, bit_index + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            ProperDescendantsRecursive(num, bit_index + 1);
        }
    }
}

void ProperDescendants(unsigned int num)
{
    ProperDescendantsRecursive(num, 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    ProperDescendants(21);
    
    return 0;
}
```

compiling and running results this output:

```
0
16
4
20
1
17
5
21
```